# Apache Spark RDD value lookup

Tags: apache-spark

I loaded data from Hbase and did some operation on that data and a paired RDD is created. I want to use the data of this RDD in my next function. I have half million records in RDD.
Can you please suggest performance effective way of reading data by key from the paired RDD .

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Only from Driver, you can use `rdd.lookup(key)` to return all values associated with the provided key.

Answer (score 1):

That is a tough use case.  Can you use some datastore and index it?

Check out Splice Machine (Open Source).

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
rdd2 = rdd1.sortByKey()
rdd2.lookup(key)
```

This will be fast.

Comment: On 70K items: with sortByKey, 70K lookups (so 70K Spark jobs) took a half hour for me; in contrast, without sortByKey it was unfinished after over an hour when I stopped it.  (local[5])

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
rddName.take(5)
```

where 5 is the number of top most elements to be returned. You can change the number accordingly. 
Also to read the very first element, you can use

```
rddName.first
```

Comment: I have to pass a key and get the value.

Comment: You can use mapValues()